# Comparing spectrogram similarity over time

Tags: matlab, audio, cross-correlation, acoustics

I have a data set of spectrograms from moving audio recorders. As the recorders get closer, I expect the spectrograms to become more "similar". I expect this "similarity" to be a function of distance and frequency.

I would like to create a 3d plot or image that has distance and frequency on the x and y, and "similarity" on z. I am not sure how to define this similarity. Is there a standardized way of comparing similar signals in this way?

Comment: Try "cross correlation".  That should give what you need.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation

Answer (score 1):

For spectrogram similarity, I suggest using a metric from image processing known as SSIM - Structural Similarity Index Metric. It is a quantity between $[0,1]$ which denotes the similarity between two images.

The paper is called [Image Quality Assessment: From Error Visibility to Structural Similarity](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1284395). The MATLAB function [`ssimval()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/ssim.html) will give you the metric.

Comment: What about new samples with higher values? The scaling to `[0, 1]` means it can work only if all the data set is given in prior.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use Dynamic Time Warping (DTW). This is a widely used technique to compare and time align information. In this case you will be using spectral slices as features for comparison. The result of your DTW can also provide you an overall similariy value.

For feature comparison you can select several metrics but I believe that cosine distance would be the best for your case.

A nice example can be found [here](https://github.com/pollen-robotics/dtw/blob/master/examples/MFCC%20%2B%20DTW.ipynb).